# Single Single On with Azure B2C does not work across domain and cross-platform applications

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c

I have struggled to find a seamless way to achieve automatic single sign-on between multiple sites.

SSO needs to be implemented across sites that are cross-platform consisting of SPA,.Net MVC or Asp.Net forms
Some are hosted on Azure while few are on-premise.

I tried MSAL.Js and Hello.js but they do not work cross-domain. 
and if we have other sites (.Net MVC) which are not using these libraries, they do not share sso session, as they will have different implementation of sso.

Also I am not sure if making repeated B2C call to check active session is the most cost effective and the appropriate way to achieve SSO.

So can we :

1] Achieve Single sign-on without requiring any code level changes.just through SSO configuration on the azure portal.
   or we do need to write custom code to configure each site.

2] Can the user be signed-on automatically without requiring the user to initiate sign on click, if there is an active B2C session.

Have not seen MSAL or hello.js working even across https://web1.domain.com  and https://web2.domain.com this libraries do not create session at the parent domain ".domain.com".

3] How do we share the session across different platform (.Net MVC,Webforms,Javascript client,SPA)

4] Achieve global sign out when user logs out from any of the website

Comment: How do you have your policies set up in your B2C tenant? How many of each kind, which apps are using which ones, etc...

Comment: All the policies have been configured with single sign on scope as tenant. also just to let you know single sing on works if initiated with a  click. what we were expecting is it should not have required any user action. when the page loads user should be automatically logged in.